# Passing data properly in android?

Tags: java, android, video

I have this in my first activity:

```
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener _itemClickLis = new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        // Now we want to actually get the data location of the file
        String [] proj={MEDIA_DATA};
        // We request our cursor again
        _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                proj, // Which columns to return
                null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        // We want to get the column index for the data uri
        int count = _cursor.getCount();
        //
        _cursor.moveToFirst();
        //
        _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(MEDIA_DATA);
        // Lets move to the selected item in the cursor
        _cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        // And here we get the filename
        String filename = _cursor.getString(_columnIndex);
        //*********** You can do anything when you know the file path :-)
        showToast(filename);

        Intent i = new Intent("com.ave.EDITORSCREEN");
        i.putExtra("mnt/sdcard-ext", _ID);
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

This is not the full code, but as the full code gathers all the video thumbnails from the sd card and displays them along with their path's (in toasts). I want to be able to click a thumbnail and have the data passed on to the next activity to be played, stopped, paused, etc. You can see where I have passed the data in the first activity:

```
public class Editor extends Activity {
ImageButton video1;
int isClicked = 0;
ImageButton audio;
int isClicked1 = 0;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editor);

    video1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.video1);
    video1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isClicked == 0) {
                video1.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_pressed);
                isClicked = 1;
            } else {
                video1.setImageResource(R.drawable.video1);
                isClicked = 0;
            }
          }
     });

    audio = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.audio);
    audio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isClicked1 == 0) {
                audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_pressed);
                isClicked1 = 1;
            } else {
                audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio);
                isClicked1 = 0;
            }
          }
      });
    }
}
```

I imagine to get the data I will need to put

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("mnt/sdcard-ext");
```

But where the onCreate method? Or is this even the right way to get the passed data? And lastly how can I can I play the video? Is there some sort of code for say a video player? If so where would I place this in my final activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to do it in the `onCreate()` method, but why not?  Where else would you put it?

If you are looking for any sort of documentation, I would recommend checking out the [Android Developers Java(Android)Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/package-summary.html).  The [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/index.html) have a great site in general, all about Android.  I think a good place to start with Android [Audio/Video is here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html).

Generally, you would set up the layout of your MediaPlayer interface (Play/Pause buttons and views) in `onCreate()` and also setup your click/touch listeners to be executed when input is received.

For a first programming course, it looks like you are doing pretty well.  Good Luck!