# How to pass selected data over to next activity android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Im creating a simple app which is for example i got 10 table row with check box and user click on 3 box and press next, i wan to print out only the 3 row the use clicked and adding extra button/icon beside it. Is it possible? please help ! Thank you !

Comment: Google *pass data in bundle to next activity*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing data properly in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998564/passing-data-properly-in-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can use append your selected string to StringBuilder and pass it through Bundle.

Comment: @GlynnNeo Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167088/appending-with-stringbuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to pass data to another `Activity` you can use `Intent`s and putting your data as extra :

here is a sample :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("data", "My data in second activity");
startActivity(intent);
```

and for retrieving data in `SecondActivity` :

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
```

Comment: Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens for intent.putExtra

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `putExtra` and pass an `ArrayList` of `String`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Recipes2.this, XMLParser.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("myList", (ArrayList<String>) myList);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent)
```

For more information check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).